# How can we query the login passwords for websites saved by Google Chrome browser?

Tags: password, chrome

A while ago, I  asked for how to query the login passwords for websites saved by Firefox browser, and received [a working solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149525/query-firefox-password-database). Now I was wondering how to query the login passwords for websites saved by Google Chrome browser outside it? Thanks.

I found a solution [here](https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/export-chrome-passwords/) using `sqlite3`. When it works, it doesn't ask me to provide master password which I have set for Google Chrome browser, as when I used the solution for firefox. I was wondering if I am missing something.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome stores its passwords in a SQLite database, like Firefox, but with different names. The database is the file `Login Data` in your profile directory. You can view its contents with an SQLite interface. For example, using the command line tool `sqlite3`:

```
 $ sqlite3 ~/.config/google-chrome/System\ Profile/Login\ Data
SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> select origin_url, username_value, signon_realm from logins;
…
```

In `sqlite3`, you can use `.tables` to list the available tables and `.schema` to see the list of columns in each table.

If Chrome is currently using this profile, the database file will be locked. To view it with `sqlite3`, make a copy first.

You don't need a master password to dump the database because Chrome does not have a master password feature. [It used to](https://www.julianevansblog.com/2013/12/how-to-set-master-password-in-google-chrome.html), but that feature was removed in Chrome 48 which came out in January 2016.

Chrome may use your system's password storage instead. It uses the Gnome keyring or the KDE wallet if available. I don't know what it uses to detect the availability of the system keyring. If Chrome has always used the system keyring on your system, its password database will be empty.

To view the contents of the Gnome keyring interactively, use [Seahorse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seahorse_(software)). There are tools to access it in scripts, including a [`gnomekeyring` Python library](http://mindbending.org/en/series/bending-gnome-keyring-with-python) and the [`keyring`](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/) Python library as well as the command line tool `secret-tool` from [libsecret](https://developer.gnome.org/libsecret/).

If you want to store your passwords in an encrypted form, make sure that Chrome is using your system keyring, and make sure that your keyring is encrypted. Alternatively, make sure that your home directory, if not your whole disk, is encrypted.

Comment: Thanks. I will read https://superuser.com/questions/969484/what-is-gnome-keyring-seahorse-and-why-its-storing-my-passwords-in-plaintext later

Comment: The passwords seem to be stored in BLOB format in the database, so I wonder what needs to be done to see them as plain text?

Answer (score 0):

I found and tested myself Python script provided by https://rtfm.co.ua/en/chromium-linux-keyrings-secret-service-passwords-encryption-and-store/ . It works nicely (Google Chrome, Fedora Linux 33). I found master password using Seahorse/Password manager.